# Finding the minimum of a nested list

Tags: haskell

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
let i = [(6, 0.2), (4, 0.9), (12, 0.1)]
```

I'm interested in finding the element that has the smallest second element:

```
(12, 0.1)
```

I was trying to use minimum, but obviously that doesn't work. How can I find the minimum of a nested list?

```
minimum (\(x, y) -> y) lst
```

Comment: icktoofay's answer is correct, but I wanted to point out that you do not have a nested list, but rather a list of pairs. They're very different things and it's important to realize that tuples are not lists :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`minimumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aminimumBy), [`comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v%3acomparing), and [`snd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asnd):

```
minimumBy (comparing snd)
```